# how to write a script for connecting to mysql by TCP/IP over SSH?

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

As shown in the title, I want to open mysql at my local terminal.
I wrote 2 lines:

```
ssh -i pem user@1.1.1.1   #Log in to server with password
mysql -h xxx -u user -p  #connect to MySQL with password
```

Is it possible to make it in one line?  Or Can I write it in a script?
Really fresh on Bash:)

Comment: `man ssh` should answer your question.

Comment: ssh (SSH client) is a program for logging into a remote machine and for executing commands on a remote machine. Sounds reasonable. But what should I do to execute mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last part of ssh's synopsis in the man page is **[command]**.

Since mysql is a screen based program you need to run ssh with -t

This should work:

```
ssh -t -i pem user@1.1.1.1 "mysql -h xxx -u user -p"
```

Comment: I tried this line. Only I exit from server, "mysql.." will be executed. But what I want is "mysql..." automatically executed when I login the server.

Comment: That has nothing to do with ssh, then. that'd be something you put into your .bashrc or whatever file.

Comment: @anna Tested it specifically with mysql for you and found out that it gets stuck unless you use ssh's -t option. Does that fix your problem? (cause frankly I didn't fully understand your comment).

Comment: Wooooo, so cool! It's exactly what I want. I read man ssh, and began to know the difference of -t and -L. Thanks so much! By the way, do you know a good bash tutorial?

Comment: Try [this list](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist) of bash tutorials. They're graded there.